# Run powershell queries against SCCM reports

Tags: powershell, sccm-2012, report

My company is using SCCM.  I have run access to one of the default reports called "Monitoring\Overview\Reporting\Reports\Network\MAC - Computers for a specific MAC address".

It returns all computer names attached to a specified MAC.  I'd like to run this report from PowerShell and dump the computer names either straight to console or a text file.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what cmdlet I'd use to do this.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at this: [Download SSRS Parameterized Reports in PDF with PowerShell](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2011/10/11/download-ssrs-parameterized-reports-in-pdf-with-powershell/)?

Comment: I have not, but I'll give it a read.  Thank you!